# Swift: Animating stretch & shrink of an image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

I am trying to animate the stretch and shrink of a lightsaber in my app. Currently I have everything working except for the stretching/shrinking of the lightsaber.

Ideally, I would like to be able to have the bottom anchor of actual saber be flush below the top anchor of saber handle. I've been able to achieve somewhat well with Auto Layout constraints. However, I'm struggling to find the right code for animations. As you can see from my code, I have tried frame.size.height/width, however that only moves the frame of the saber (not the handle). The line with frame.size.height achieves what I want in terms of making it stretch/grow, but it's a very bootleg way of doing it.

The current frame.size.height/width method only shifts the images, how would I achieve the stretch/shrink capability? Is it possible to achieve it with the multiplier function from Auto Layout constraints?

```
@objc func lightsaberTapped() {
    print("lightsaber open!")

    if mainView.saberImage.isHidden == true {
        mainView.saberImage.isHidden = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

            self.mainView.saberImage.frame.size.height -= 500
//          self.mainView.saberImage.frame.size.width += 20

            }, completion: nil)
        lightsaberModel.turnSaberOnAudio.play()
    } else {
        mainView.saberImage.isHidden = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

            self.mainView.saberImage.frame.size.height += 500
//          self.mainView.saberImage.frame.size.width += 20

        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: try with transform

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Would you be willing to elaborate?

Comment: ok, i will try to provide an answer

Comment: you want scale only height or both height and width?

Comment: ideally I would like to make the saber image as small as possible and then extend it out to a certain height and certain width

Comment: ok, you are using constraints?

Comment: yes, currently I have auto layout constraints, bottom anchor of the saber is connected to the top anchor of the lightsaber handle

Comment: let me know if my answer helps you or if you need further explanation, Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is the frame animation while you have constraints, you need 1 of 2 or animate constrains or remove it and animate with frame property, in that case you need to make sure that your `UIImageView` is added with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

To animate width and height in `Autolayout` system you need to get the constraint reference as `IBOutlet` and animate the constant property inside an animation block,

this is a very small example

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    }
    @IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = self.imageHeightConstraint.constant - 10
            self.imageWidthConstraint.constant = self.imageWidthConstraint.constant - 10
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Reinier! I played around with the code and was able to get it to work.

Comment: Can you provide me a solution with animating via the frame property ?

Comment: @ZahurafzalMirza Can you explain which problem are you facing?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I  am posting a link to my question here. Hope you can help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63915777/custom-uiview-animation-for-ui-ux-interaction-with-stretch-and-reposition-uiview

Answer (score 0):

First add constraints for width and height

```
 @IBOutlet weak var saberImageHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
 @IBOutlet weak var saberImageWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Try this to get animation while resize frame.

```
if mainView.saberImage.isHidden == true 
{
    mainView.saberImage.isHidden = false
    self.saberImageHeightConstraint.constant -= 500
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()    
        self.viewDidLayoutSubviews()    
    }, completion: nil)

    lightsaberModel.turnSaberOnAudio.play()
} 
else 
{
    mainView.saberImage.isHidden = true
    self.saberImageHeightConstraint.constant += 500
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```